# MySQL Nested Loop In Store Procedure - Search Entire Table From All Values in Another Column

Tags: mysql, search, stored-procedures, nested, nested-loops

What I am trying to do is create a procedure that will search all the columns in my main table for all the values that I have stored in a single column in another table. Then, I want to update a column on my main table with all the search results that were found in the table.

So for instance, I want to search for “Access”, “Business, “Login”. Those are my keywords that I have stored out in the ca.keywords table.

Then, the main table, ca.base, has a bunch of text columns and I want to search all of them for the above words.

If there is a match for all 3 of the above words, I want to update the ca.base.keywords_found column to “Access & Business & Login”.

I cannot figure out how to make the nested loop work since I need to use variables defined at the beginning in both of my loops, so I don't see how I can write multiple begin statements in the same stored procedure as is often suggested.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mkline`@`%` PROCEDURE `table_keywords_search_ca_base`()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE search_column VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'CA' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'BASE' AND `DATA_TYPE` = 'TEXT' ORDER BY `ORDINAL_POSITION`;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
-- Process the next column
FETCH cur1 INTO search_column;

-- If we're done, stop the loop
IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

BEGIN

DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE keyword VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT `keywords` FROM `ca`.`keywords`;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done2 = TRUE;

    OPEN cur2;

search_loop: LOOP

FETCH cur2  INTO keyword;

    -- If we're done, stop the loop
IF done2 THEN
  LEAVE search_loop;
END IF;

    SET @keyword = replace(@keyword,' ','%');
    SET @keyword = CONCAT(''%', @keyword, '%'');
    SET @new_query = CONCAT("UPDATE CA.BASE SET KEYWORDS_FOUND = ", @keyword, "& ", "WHERE ", SEARCH_COLUMN, " LIKE '%", @keyword, "%'");

PREPARE stmt FROM @new_query;
EXECUTE stmt ;

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur2;
END;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Comment: `BEGIN...END` are basically the equivalent of `{...}` in many other programming languages.

Comment: So I can reference my variable from above in a new begin statement?

Comment: As far as I have experienced, MySQL has the same scoping rules as languages like C/C++/Java/etc... i.e. variables declared earlier within the block, or earlier in an outer block that the current code is nested in, are in scope.